# Refreshing an Ext JS Panel that is not attached to a store?

Tags: javascript, extjs, refresh

I need to refresh content on my page every 60 seconds.

However, due to the customization of the panel, with data sorted into a tree structure based on a property, I haven't been able to set the store as a property to the panel.

This is what I believe to be the relevant code:

```
refreshContent: function () {

    var mainMenuPanel = Ext.getCmp("FirstTreePanel");
    mainMenuPanel.removeAll();

    this.onPanelRender();

},

init: function (application) {

    this.control({
        "#FirstTreePanel": {
            render: this.onPanelRender
        }
    });

    // We add a listener for the refresh event.
    var self = this;
    this.application.on("refreshContent", function() {
        self.refreshContent();
    });
}
```

The problem is that the panel essentially becomes unusable, with the panel expanding and collapsing randomly.

Is there a specific way to handle this?

Edit: Here is the code in my app.js that is firing the event.

```
    var self = this;
    var task = {
        run: function () {

            // Fire off the event for the panels to refresh.
            self.fireEvent("refreshContent");
        },
        interval: 1000 * 10//config.refreshTime
    }

    Ext.TaskManager.start(task);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

You're multiplying 1000*10, which is every 10 second.  You should update it to 1000 * 60.

Comment: Sorry actually that specific controller is only one of many that is listening to the refresh content event. I added code to my original post.